# Reusing React 'key'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know it's normal to reuse react key from component to component. In `Row` component i got `key` From column component and reuse it for mapping `Row` childrens

```js
const Table = props => {
  const { data, children, showHeader } = props;
  return (
    <div className="table">
      {showHeader && <TableHead children={children} />}
      {data.map(data => {
        return <Row key={data.id} data={data} children={children} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const TableHead = props => {
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <div className="table-row">
      {children.map(col => {
        const { title, field, width } = col.props;
        return (
          <div className="table-col" key={field}>
            <div
              className="table-cell table-cell-head"
              style={{
                width: width
              }}
            >
              {title}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

//HERE I GET key from Column component and reuse it for rows (number of columns === number of rows)
const Row = props => {
  const { data, children } = props;
  return (
    <div className="table-row">
      {children.map(col => {
        let { field, ...rest } = col.props;
        const { key } = col;
        return (
          <div className="table-col" key={key}>
            {React.cloneElement(col, {
              ...rest,
              field,
              data
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Column = props => {
  const { field, data, width } = props;
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: width
      }}
      className="table-cell"
      key={data.id}
    >
      {data[field]}
    </div>
  );
};

const HeadRow = props => {
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <div className="table-row">
      {children.map(col => {
        const { title, field, width } = col.props;
        return (
          <div className="table-col" key={field}>
            <div
              className="table-cell table-cell-head"
              style={{
                width: width
              }}
            >
              {title}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const initData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Ivan",
      age: "My age is 27",
      enabled: true,
      myListValue: [
        {
          myName: "Duncan",
          myDescription: "Immortal!",
          myGroup: "Immortal",
          createDate: "2019-08-12T05:21:28Z"
        }
      ],
      lastChanged: new Date(),
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Vitaly",
      age: `My age is 25\nMy age is 25\nMy age is 25\n`,
      lastChanged: new Date(),
      enabled: true,
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Sergey",
      age: "My age is 29",
      enabled: true,
      myListValue: [
        {
          myName: "Duncan",
          myDescription: "Immortal!",
          myGroup: "Immortal",
          createDate: "2019-08-12T05:21:28Z"
        },
        {
          myName: "Connor",
          myDescription: "Immortal2!",
          myGroup: "MacLeods",
          createDate: "2019-08-12T05:21:28Z"
        },
        {
          myName: "John Snow",
          myDescription: "(he knows nothing)",
          myGroup: "WhiteWalkers",
          createDate: "2019-08-12T05:21:28Z"
        },
        {
          myName: "Jamie Lannister",
          myDescription: "Lannisters always pay their debts",
          myGroup: "Red castle",
          createDate: "2019-08-12T05:21:28Z"
        }
      ],
      lastChanged: new Date()
    }
  ];

ReactDOM.render(
<Table data={initData} showHeader={true} sortableConfig={{}}>
        <Column key="0" field="name" width={150} title="Name" sortable="true" />
        <Column key="1" field="age" width={150} title="AGe" sortable="true" />
      </Table>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.table-row {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}

.table-col {
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.table-col:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.table-cell {
  white-space: pre-line;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-cell-head {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: From as far as i know the key property should be unique within its siblings. The children of the parent component can use the same key again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed.

Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give them a **stable identity**, and they only make sense in the context of the surrounding array, so it doesn't matter if two isolated lists have elements with equal keys as long as they are not equal inside the same list (repeated ids). There is no problem with the following code

```js
{
    arr.map((item,index) =>{
        //defining key only once per `arr` iteration
        const key = uniqueId(index)
        return(
            <div key={key}>
                 {
                    arr2.map((item, index) => <span key={key} />)
                 }
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Note that the key is only relevant within a particular parent React element. React won’t try to “match up” elements with the same keys between different parents. (React doesn’t have idiomatic support for moving a host instance between different parents without re-creating it.) [Font](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/)

See the [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)